# Exclude pages from Jetpack's "Top Posts & Pages" widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, jetpack

I have the following scenario. (WordPress with Jetpack)

Certain "custom" pages only display something if data (e.g. search term) is provided. If not, the pages are normally "blank". As they are being accessed (via link including query vars) they are accounted for in the stats. But... If you click them under "Top Posts & Pages" (widget) they are just blank.

Is there a way to not list those specific pages under "Top Posts & Pages"? Or can I maybe redirect the stats from a subpage to a parent page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to your questions depends largely on which "Top Posts & Pages" plugin you're using right now. Please update your question and add a link to said plugin (assuming you're using one, and that it's not a custom widget included by your theme) so we can look into it and provide suggestions.

Comment: OK, sry I'm not a WordPress specialist. I assumed this to be default. I do use Jetpack plugin and I guess it's provided by that one.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Please check the answer below, if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into `jetpack_widget_get_top_posts` to exclude these pages from the Top Posts & Pages widget.

Add the following code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function wp653886_exclude_from_top_posts( $posts, $post_ids, $count ) {

    $page_ids_to_exclude = array( 144, 764, 876 ); // Put here the IDs of the pages you wish to exclude.

    foreach ( $posts as $k => $post ) {
        // Remove this item from the list
        if ( in_array( $post['post_id'],  $page_ids_to_exclude ) ) {
            unset( $posts[$k] );
        }
    }

    return $posts;

}
add_filter( 'jetpack_widget_get_top_posts', 'wp653886_exclude_from_top_posts', 10, 3 );
```

Edit the `$page_ids_to_exclude` array to add the IDs of the pages you want to exclude from the widget and you're good to go.

Comment: Unfortunately this affects the number of titles displayed from the top post and pages widget if those excluded are in the top X posts and/or pages